# DB design for alternative components

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out the "best way" to design a database for a product configurator, where there are Items and Components. Now each Item can have multiple Components, where (potentially) any Component can have other Component(s) which can be its valid substitute(s) or incompatible with it.

P.S. Sorry for the noob question and for my poor English.

Comment: From your question thus far it seems `Items` has a 1-many with `Components` and Components can reference itself?

Comment: But in this way can a Component have multiple substitutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items and Components relationship can be done by one to many approach. You can design your tables by connecting primary keys and foreign keys to each other.

My suggestion for your other problem is that to use "parent_id" approach. A component table can have a "parent_id" column, so you can set the actual component and its substitutes.

Here is the example Components table:

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | item_id | parent_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 | null      |
|  2 |       1 | 1         |
|  3 |       1 | 1         |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

The table above, item_id = 1 has three components with ids 1,2 and 3. The component with id=1 has two substitutes which are 2 and 3.

**UPDATE**

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | item_id | parent_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 | null      |
|  2 |       1 | 1         |
|  3 |       1 | 2         |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

The table above, component_id 3 is the substitute of component_id 2 (look at its parent_id), component_id 2 is the substitute of component_id 1.

Comment: In your example, what if the Component_id 2 has as substitute also Component_id 3? Forgive my limits but I am just starting with database concepts.

Comment: it still works. parent_id means the answer of the question "Whose substitute am I?" for a component.  I updated the answer. Check that out

Comment: ok about that, but now for what I can understand Component 3 is a substitute of just Component 2, not both Component 2 AND Component 1...

Comment: It is all depend on your code architecture. This is a data structure. You can see "whose substitue is who" by looking at component_id and paranet_id. Just look at row 3, id=3, item_id=1, parent_id=2 which means "component 3 is the component of item_id=1 and it is the substitute of component 2"

Comment: In your last sentence "component 3 is the component of item_id=1 and it is the substitute of component 2" it is still not explicitly defined that "component 3 is also a substitute of component 1", so I guess that this must be inferred from te fact that "component 2 is a substitute of component 1"....

Comment: It is up to your assigned value. The design that I described provides you to ability of assigning more than one substitute to a component. Describe a scenario and lets check if it fits to our design model or not :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, and apologize if I'm so repetitive in my questions.
And if a Component belong to multiple Items? I guess I must use a third table (more or less as in the reply of Wei Huang).....

Comment: The first information was "Now each Item can have multiple Components" :) It was one-to-many approach for item&component relation. In this case there should be a router table which has repeated rows. OR, if you want to use this structure with "parent_id" and just two tables with no repeat rows, you can keep string values in "parent_id" columns with commas such as "1,2". It wouldn't be good idea for your queries with joins, but if you have a ram-based data structure at your code side and these tables stand just for initialization, it may be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Item-Component table like this:

```
+--+------------+---------+-----------+
|id|component_id|parent_id|parent_type|
+--+------------+---------+-----------+
| 1|           1|        1|          i|
| 2|           2|        1|          c|
+--+------------+---------+-----------+
```

where, the value of `parent_type` shows the parent is `item` column (with `i`) or `component` column (with `c`)

Item table like this:

```
+--+-------+
|id|content|
+--+-------+
| 1|    xxx|
+--+-------+
```

Component table like this:

```
+--+-------+-------------+
|id|content|other_columns|
+--+-------+-------------+
| 1|    xxx|          ...|
| 2|    xxx|          ...|
+--+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: And the connection between Component and Item tables to Item-Component table will be one-to-many, right?

Comment: Yes, `Item-Component` table is a connection table. According the `parent_type` column, the `parent_id` can be a `Item` id or a `Component` id.